# Animation not working when enabled double buffer in WinForms c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Animation not working when enabled double buffer in my form. Here is my form code with simple animation. A panel slide-out animation is not working like animation. Slid-in animation is working well. Any idea?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    Timer timer1 = new Timer
    {
        Interval = 100
    };

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int currentheight = panel1.Height;
        int maxheight = 137;
        int minheight = 0;
        if (currentheight == maxheight)
        {
            do
            {
                panel1.Height--;
            }
            while (panel1.Height > minheight);
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                panel1.Height++;
            }
            while (panel1.Height < maxheight);
        }

        timer1.Stop();

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        timer1.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Tick is supposed to happen at Interval periods. Don't put the loops in there, make __it__ the loop body and don't stop the timer in it until the animation is really done! This also means that you should initialize the values outside of the tick..

Comment: I understood. Thank you @TaW.